# fluid button in physics

Tags: physics

Please help. I am following the ICE text tutorial and I have my text selected and I'm trying to use 'fluid' in the 'physics' section. The tutorial says the fluid button should be there but it isn't. When I select my plane the fluid button appears but not when the text is selected.

Comment: What ICE text tutorial? Not everyone watches BlenderGuru etc. Try to give specifics when asking, Blender version etc. See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/608/12

Comment: @AJH the text object is not a mesh, you probably need to first convert it to a mesh with ALT+C in object mode.